# Why could I need to fsck check the root file system?

Tags: fsck, root-filesystem

This could sound like a rather obvious question, but we all know that **soft-checking of any partition** is sometimes a need, and we perform it in cases like unstabilities found, lost files or (mandatorily) on power outages.

But I think it could be good to know the **fundamentals** (the reason) of software checking the most important partition: the root file system.

So my **questions** are:

- **Why** (when) could I need to perform a `fsck` on my **root file system**?
- What are the **symptoms** that show a `fsck` must be performed?
- Are all answers the **same** for root and non-root partitions?

Comment: Sounds as if you are looking for documentation rather then asking a question about a specific problem. See https://docs.freebsd.org/44doc/smm/03.fsck/paper.pdf and http://www.adminschoice.com/repairing-unix-file-system-fsck

Comment: No, @bodhi.zazen , I was trying trying to cooperate in writing a Wiki. I think the question-answer method of Stack Exchange has mainly that objective. Thanks for the links, anyway.